Getting Assertion Error: col should be column while assigning a value to pyspark df
I am trying to assign some value to an empty dataframe but getting error:
Getting Assertion Error: col should be column
Refer the code below for reference-
path = 'xyz/zjx/abc.parquet'  

df = spark.read.parquet(path)
        
row_count = df.count()
        
columns = StructType([StructField('Table',
                            StringType(), True),
                      StructField('Count',
                            StringType(), True),
                      StructField('Path',
                            StringType(), True)])
        
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = emp_RDD,
                                   schema = columns)
df = df.withColumn('Count',row_count).withColumn('Path',path)
df.show()


I don't think you're using withColumn correctly... Those column names are already part of the schema. And, as the error says, the values must be column types, but you provided string /number

I tried string also but still same issue, Also I have tried integertype schema but no luck

The schema isn't the issue. The second parameter to withColumn needs to be a column object, not a single value

In that case what would be the best approach here, the task is to create a dataframe which will have row count of 3 different dataframes

Just create one with the exact rows you need? spark.createDataFrame(data = [['Table', 'abc'], ['Count', count], ['Path', path']], schema = columns)

or use lit from pyspark.sql.functions? e.g. lit(row_count) https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html
